# JMX Html Adaptor

Tags: java, jmx

I'm looking for a simple and straightforward way to add JMX capacities to application, preferably exposed via http. Below is simple code snippet, which, I suspect, should run http server on 8000. And I should be able to access it via `http://localhost:8000`. However page can't be opened. I can't find proper documentation how it is supposed to work.

jmxtools-1.2.jar is included to classpath. Java version - 1.6

```
import javax.management.MBeanServerFactory;
import javax.management.ObjectName;
import com.sun.jdmk.comm.HtmlAdaptorServer;

public class JmxHttpAdapter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            com.sun.jdmk.comm.HtmlAdaptorServer adapter = new HtmlAdaptorServer(8000);
            MBeanServerFactory.createMBeanServer().registerMBean(adapter, new ObjectName("Adaptor:name=html,port=8000"));
            adapter.start();
            Thread.sleep(100000);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure why that adaptor is not working, but you can find documentation in Chapter 2 of the [Java Dynamic Management Kit 5.1 Tools Reference Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19698-01/816-7608/index.html).

MX4J also has an [HTTP Adaptor](http://mx4j.sourceforge.net/docs/ch03s23.html) which is also kind of old, but you may find it better documented.

You should take a look at [Jolokia](http://www.jolokia.org/). It is more contemporary and still under active development. It is an HTTP based REST agent with several options for installation including a [WAR](http://www.jolokia.org/jolokia-agent-parent/jolokia-war/index.html) and a [Java Agent](http://www.jolokia.org/jolokia-agent-parent/jolokia-jvm/index.html). That does not get you a UI though, although there's plenty of tools you can use with it. The same developer is working on a UI project for Jolokia called [Aji](https://github.com/rhuss/aji) but I am not sure what state is in right now.

Here's a few references to UIs built for Aji:

- [Jolokia + Highcharts = JMX for human beings](http://nurkiewicz.blogspot.com/2011/03/jolokia-highcharts-jmx-for-human-beings.html)
- [JMX over HTTP with Jolokia and javascript](http://jmwikblom.blogspot.com/2012/10/jmx-over-http-with-jolokia-and.html)

Comment: It's ridiculous, but this port has been busy. No clue why I have not received exception.